# How to get the number of elements checked on a p:selectManyCheckbox with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

What i'm trying is to get the number of selected/checked items on a `p:SelectManyCheckbox`:

This is what i've tried so far but i get always `1` on the console.

```
function hasSelectedItems() {

 var iLen  =document.getElementById("north_form:rvcombo").elements; 
 console.log(iLen.length);

};
```

This is my HTML :

```
<h:form id="north_form"> 
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="rvcombo" widgetVar="rend" label="Rendez-vous"  value="#{dyna.selectedstateOptions}" styleClass="combo" onHide="activateCounter();hasSelectedItems();" onShow="deactivateCounter();">  
    <f:selectItems value="#{dyna.etatExamOptions}" />  
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" global="false"/>
</h:form>
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cnt = 0;
var o = document.getElementById("north_form:rvcombo").getElementsByTagName('input');
for ( var i in o ) {
    if ( o[i].type=='checkbox' ) {
        if ( o[i].checked ) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}
return cnt;
```

Comment: i have to wait for 7 minutes to accept the answer ;)